# UITableView Prototype Cell error EXC_i386_INVOP

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Hello I started to learn swift and for a small project and i'm using a UITableView but I'm having an error when I try to register a nib that has my prototype cell (vwTblCell.xib)

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)**

This is where I get the error:

```
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

And this is the code that I use.

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TblCell

    cell.lblCell.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat
{
    return 44
}
}
```

TblCell.swift

```
class TblCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCell: UIButton!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Have you delegated ?

Comment: you are missing the following delegates-->class yourClass: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // ...
}'

Comment: I already have the delegates I forgot to add them in the question

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: It seems like I forgot to add a referencing outlet in the storyboard